# Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, admob, google-play-services

I have imported a procject it was with admob but now cannot compile my project beacuse of this error..
I was trying to add in all my gradle dependecies but same error happens

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.pom
    file:/D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/10.2.0/play-services-10.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :android > project :BaseGameUtils
```

and this is my build.gradle (BaseGamesUtils)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I also removed from here and added to build.gradle (Module: android) but same error same on build.gradle( Project: MyProject ) any help will be very appriciated, I'm spendin 3 days now for this error..

As I see:

> file:/D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
>   don't even exist.. and project is looking there...

Everything is updated like sdk and gradle to 3.3 but nothing helps...

Comment: what do you mean by SDK update? Have you update Google Play service ? check 10.2.0 folder is present in ..\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services folder ?

Comment: I use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' in my other app. it works well but not in this one..
and yes I have ...\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services

Comment: What about running gradle with --info/--debug to get more information in the output (which is suggested by gradle itself by the way)?

Comment: where to write that ? I'm sorry I'm newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out thanks to Abhishek Aryan question and one other question found in stack overflow and changed the location where the maven was looking for repositories..

I added the folowing two lines on repositories:

> ```
>     maven { url "D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudioSDK/sdk/extras/android/m2repository" }
>     maven { url "D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudioSDK/sdk/extras/google/m2repository" }
> ```

so my total is:

```
 repositories {
        maven { url "D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudioSDK/sdk/extras/android/m2repository" }
        maven { url "D:/AndroidStudio/AndroidStudioSDK/sdk/extras/google/m2repository" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/' }
```

Finially after a week, xD and Thank you guys for your time and help :)